# Mongo warning: log line attempted (36kB) over max size (10kB)

Tags: mongodb

I have used mongodb running with codeigiter.
However, when I checked the log, I discovered the error content.

> I COMMAND  [conn80191] warning: log line attempted (36kB) over max
>   size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... command news.post command:
>   count { count: "post", query: { active: 1, id: { $in: [ 0, 258195,
>   258201] } }, $db: "news" } planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 }
>   keysExamined:8361 docsExamined:4329 numYields:84 reslen:44 locks:{
>   Global: { acquireCount: { r: 170 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r:
>   85 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 85 } } } protocol:op_query
>   1447ms

Lots of requests,
We wish everyone help.
Thanks!

Comment: Server log messages are not really a topic for Stack Overflow. You can ask about configuring those on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. From a "coding" perspective the message is essentially triggered by **excessively long query statements**. A likely cause of which is commonly putting 1000's of arguments within `$in`, which you really should not do

Comment: Further to the error message, the max line size MongoDB will log is 10kB. You have a slow query (>100ms) which is by default logged by MongoDB. However the whole log line which includes your query is 36kB, which is more than 3x the maximum log line. Note that a ~10kB query is already big, so a ~36kB query is excessively big and will not be performant (hence the query being slow). You might want to revisit your queries to make sure you don't have such a big query.

Answer (score 3):

This means a write operation took longer than `100ms` to complete.
But this is a huge write statement apparently. 
You can't log a line that;s more then `10K` in size, and that's already a lot!
At the end of the line you should be able to see how long the write actually took.

To get this log statement out of your log files you should either make your write faster if that speed of the write is to slow for you or,
you could increase the the `slowms`, check

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/